# We need to go deeper - Deep accessing JSON & array with foreach loop in Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Not absolutely new to Java Script but still a novice in some aspects, including accessing JSON objects and arrays. I tried different syntax and options with []array accessing, however failed.

[I would like to access the JSON file at this location.](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&APPID=7b67b3fc2a0559b8301bd032e8f2f1c7)

```
{
  "coord": {
    "lon": -0.13,
    "lat": 51.51
  },
  "weather": [{
    "id": 521,
    "main": "Rain",
    "description": "shower rain",
    "icon": "09d"
  }],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 289.89,
    "pressure": 1002,
    "humidity": 87,
    "temp_min": 288.15,
    "temp_max": 291.48
  },
  "visibility": 10000,
  "wind": {
    "speed": 5.1,
    "deg": 210,
    "gust": 10.8
  },
  "rain": {
    "1h": 0.25
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 40
  },
  "dt": 1569596940,
  "sys": {
    "type": 1,
    "id": 1414,
    "message": 0.012,
    "country": "GB",
    "sunrise": 1569563635,
    "sunset": 1569606559
  },
  "timezone": 3600,
  "id": 2643743,
  "name": "London",
  "cod": 200
}
```

Using a foreach loop to access the data, I am not quite sure how the proper syntax would be for this.

Ultimately, I would just want to achieve the following with string literals:

Display in HTML:

```
City ID
City Weather Description
City Name
```

See code:

```
// weather api definition
let url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&APPID=7b67b3fc2a0559b8301bd032e8f2f1c7'
let weatherInfo = document.getElementById('title');

fetch(url).then(function (response) {
  return response.json();
})
.then(function(data) {
  document.getElementById('weather-info').innerHTML = '<h2 id="title"></h2>';
  document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = 'THIS IS JASOOON';
  //here is where my problems start
  let output = '<h4>Weather Info - cities</h4>';
  data.foreach((item)=> {
    console.log(item.weather)
  });

  data.foreach(function(item) {
    output += `
  <ul>
    <li> City ID: ${item.id} </li>
    <li> City Weather Description: ${item.description} </li>
    <li> City Name ${item.name} </li>
  </ul>`;

  document.getElementById('weather-info').innerHTML = output;
  });

})
.catch(err => {
  console.log('errorMessage');
});
```

Comment: um, that result does not return an array so not sure why you would be looping over it. It is returning a single result.

Comment: One quick thing that sticks out here is `foreach()` but should be `forEach()`.

Comment: data is an object, so you''l want something like `data.weather.forEach()` instead. It's just a basic object you can navigate by its property names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what all the looping is about since it is returning one city.

```js
// weather api definition
let url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&APPID=7b67b3fc2a0559b8301bd032e8f2f1c7'
let weatherInfo = document.getElementById('title');

fetch(url).then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(data) {
  
    const weather = data.weather.map(report => report.description).join(", ")
  
  
    let output = `
      <h4>Weather Info - cities</h4>
      <ul>
        <li> City ID: ${data.id} </li>
        <li> City Weather Description: ${weather} </li>
        <li> City Name ${data.name} </li>
      </ul>`;
    document.getElementById('weather-info').innerHTML = output;
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('errorMessage');
  });
```

```html
<div id="weather-info"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the **Weather** property is an **Array**, you can iterate over it.

```js
 let url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&APPID=7b67b3fc2a0559b8301bd032e8f2f1c7'
    
         fetch(url)
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function (data) {
             
                let output = '<h4>Weather Info - cities</h4>';

                // access the weather property and loop through it
                data.weather.forEach(function (item) {
                    // log the Stringfied version
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(item));
                    output += `
                        <ul>
                            <li> City ID: ${item.id} </li>
                            <li> City Weather Description: ${item.description} </li>
                            <li> City Name ${data.name} </li>
                        </ul> <br>`;

                    document.getElementById('weather-info').innerHTML = output;
                });

            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err.message);
                console.log('errorMessage');
            });
```

```html
<div id="weather-info"></div>
```